# Unable to set start and end time when adding Outlook calendar entry

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm using this to add a calendar entry to a shared calendar (which does not add it to the shared calendar) It also does not set the start and end times it just adds the entry as an all day event. Is this even possible, I've been using this:

```
private void AddAppointment()
{
    try
    {
        var AppOutlook = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.AppointmentItem newAppointment = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)AppOutlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace oNS = AppOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient oRep = null;               
        oRep = oNS.CreateRecipient("Someone Elses Calendar");                
        newAppointment.Start = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);
        newAppointment.End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(4);
        newAppointment.Location = "remote";
        newAppointment.Body = "Test Calendar Entry";
        newAppointment.BusyStatus = Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olTentative;
        newAppointment.AllDayEvent = true;
        newAppointment.Subject = "Test Calendar Entry";
        newAppointment.Save();
        newAppointment.Display(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The following error occurred: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You told it to make it an all-day event `newAppointment.AllDayEvent = true;` Try setting it to false if you want it to be false.

Comment: As Ben mentioned, you could setting to "false", please see the link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-create-appointments?view=vs-2017

Comment: Thanks, color me foolish saw that right after posting! :{ Anyway I trired you suggestion in the link Simon, it still won;t add it to a shared calendar, just to mine. Any Ideas? Thanks